# How to navigate to account route after having access token in Shopify login

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

I'm developing the social login app for Shopify. I is used script tag to load javascript link. In site the javascript link, I got the shopify accessToken from this https://shopify.dev/api/storefront/2022-10/mutations/customerAccessTokenCreate
How can I save this accessToken to session or cookie or anything to the website know that the customer is logged in. and I can navigate them to "/account" route.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, you can potentially use localStorage js property to store the loggedin state into local storage. This is helpful especially if youw ant to redirect the users straight to /account if they try to access the login page.
More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage